# filtered lists: fading out currently filtered list and fading in same list with new filter applied

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to get a sort of rudimentary filter working. Basically, you click on a link and it filters the list (see code below). This actually works fine. However, I'd like pretty it up a bit by fading out the current list (whether it's filtered or not), and fading the list back in with the right filter applied.

Hope you get what I mean. Let me know if I don't make any sense.

**HTML:**

```
filter by: <a href="#" class="clearfilter">all</a>
<h4>venue</h4>
<a href="#location1" class="filter">location1</a>, <a href="#location2" class="filter">location2</a>
<h4>photographer</h4>
<a href="#ben" class="filter">ben</a>, <a href="#ken" class="filter">ken</a>, <a href="#sam" class="filter">sam</a>, <a href="#susan" class="filter">susan</a>
<br/><br/>
<ul>
    <li class="ken location1"><a href="#">img 01</a></li>
    <li class="ken location1"><a href="#">img 02</a></li>
    <li class="ken location2"><a href="#">img 03</a></li>
    <li class="sam location2"><a href="#">img 04</a></li>
    <li class="sam location2"><a href="#">img 05</a></li>
    <li class="ben location2"><a href="#">img 06</a></li>
    <li class="ben location2"><a href="#">img 07</a></li>
    <li class="ben location2"><a href="#">img 08</a></li>
    <li class="susan location1"><a href="#">img 09</a></li>
    <li class="susan location1"><a href="#">img 10</a></li>
    <li class="susan location2"><a href="#">img 11</a></li>
    <li class="ken location2"><a href="#">img 12</a></li>
</ul>
```

​**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filter").click( function () {
        var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
        $("li").show().not('.'+filterText).hide();
    });

    $(".clearfilter").click( function() {
        $("li").show();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
li a {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
}​
```

​

I tried the usual fadeOut() and fadeIn() again but the filter seems to be applying to the already filtered list and nothing comes back. This si why I've got the initial `show()` in this line:  `$("li").show().not('.'+filterText).hide();` because that seems to reset the list.
But if I add the show() in it won't fade properly.

Thanks in advance for your help. Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gxfBD/33/

**EDIT:**
It seems not even professionals get it right: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/. Theirs jumps about and shows items briefly that aren't supposed to be shown, too.  :/

**EDIT AGAIN (ALTERNATIVE ANSWER):**
Marc's answer below gave me the kick-start I needed to work it out. my new jQuery is below:

```
var filterText = "all";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filter").click( function () {
        filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');

        if(filterText == "all") {
            $("#gallery a").colorbox({rel:'gallery'});
        }
        else {
            $("#gallery ."+filterText+" a").colorbox({rel:filterText});
        }
        showFilterList(filterText);
    });

    $("#gallery a").colorbox({rel:'gallery'});
});

function showFilterList(value) {
    if (value == "all") {
        $("#gallery").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $("#gallery li").show(); //remove the filter so everything shows
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
        $("#gallery").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $("#gallery li").show(); //remove the filter so everything shows
            $("#gallery li").not('.'+value).hide(); //apply the new filter
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

I've also combined the colorbox plugin and added the call to my click event. This allows the "image x of y" text to be set with the new filtered number of images in the list.

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/gxfBD/74/

I gave your `<UL>` an ID and changed the JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filter").click( function () {
        var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
        $("#ulid").hide(); //hide the whole div
        $("li").show(); //remove the filter so everything shows
        $("li").not('.'+filterText).hide(); //apply the new filter
        $("#ulid").fadeIn(1000); //fade in the div
    });
});
```

Note that if you want more control over the `fadeOut()` effect, you can do the filtering within a callback, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filter").click( function () {
        var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
        $("#ulid").fadeOut(1000,
                           function(){
                             $("li").show();
                             $("li").not('.'+filterText).hide();
                           }
                      );
        $("#ulid").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

If that isn't what you're looking for, then you'll need to be more clear about what you are looking for.

Comment: Mate, that's pretty much what I'm after. thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting transition times in your hide() and show(), like so with the 1000 millisecond fade:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".filter").click( function () {
      var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
      $("li").show(1000).not('.'+filterText).hide(1000);
  });

  $(".clearfilter").click( function() {
      $("li").show(1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've tried delays, but it doesn't have the desired effect. it sort of fades out twice. 
Edit: just tried that line. again, not the desired effect. The `show` is kind of irrelevant for me. It's just there to reset ths list because I couldn't work out how to fadeOut and In again on the original list items. I may not be making much sense - I am very tired :/